# How can connect DB2 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, db2, database-connection

How can I create a connection with DB2 data base, in Visual Studio 2010?

These are the steps I already follow:

*Data on menu bar, then Add New Data Source > Database > Dataset > New Connection*

In this screen, I choose *.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB* as Data Source and *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2* as OLE DB Provider.

I also fill the server name, user and password. However, when I click to test the connection, a error window appears with the message: "Incorect parameter"

Can somebody help me?

I'm sure of the user name and password, so my doubt is related to the first 3 fields: Data Source, OLE DB Provider and Server or file name. Are they correct for a DB2 connection?

Thanks.

Comment: try looking at this [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/) if not do a google search

Comment: I've already tried this... Still not working, but thank you

Comment: well that's really not going to help any of us here it would behoove you to post your code that you have in your .config or .cs file to show us what it is you are doing without that then you're expecting us to guess as well as know your existing environment

Comment: [A Primer on Using DB2 with .NET](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030623.htm) || [Connecting to DB2 from .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DotnetDb2.aspx)

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you. How can I mark the comment as the answer so you can get pointssss?

Comment: There is Project that looks similar to what you are doing on CodeProject
This should help you in regards to posting a file to a PHP server [Connecting to DB2 from .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DotnetDb2.aspx) [A Primet on Using DB2 with .NET](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030623.htm)

Comment: Glad I could help point you in the right direction.. thanks